# Attempting to add an MQTT library from NuGet into Xamarin project

Tags: xamarin

I saw that Xamarin was now free and decided to try writing a mobile app using it instead of what another technology I was playing with.  After some various hiccups, I was able to get the new Xamarin Android project to build, deploy and run on the simulator.  I then decided to try out MQTT connectivity from it before I went any further.  No matter which MQTT library I to install from NuGet, for example the System.Net.Mqtt one from Xamarin, I get the following error:

"Could not install package 'System.Net.Mqtt 0.3.12-pre'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'MonoAndroid,Version=v6.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author."

I tried several others with no success. It does the same for the ios and Android projects.  I did try changing the Android SDK version to use for compiling, but still had the same result.  I also don't understand why it says MonoAndroid since I thought all the Mono references were changed to Xamarin?  I'm using Visual Studio 15 with Update 2.  I tried the stable Xamarin version and also tried the latest alpha.  I'm not sure what else to try, I'd really to give Xamarin a try for this project.  I did some searching and couldn't find anything that appeared to help with this issue.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use the Package Manager Console. Then, either:

1. Install the [latest version](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Net.Mqtt/) of MQTT library.
2. Or install first its dependency, [RX-Main](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Rx-Main/) and then MQTT.

If you still get an error, please share with us the Log that is shown in the PM Console.

Comment: I created a new project just to have a clean one, which coincidentally the iOS module failed to create/load but that's for another day I guess, and tried the install from the Package Manager Console.  I created a gist with the output here: https://gist.github.com/rmoquin/313fc510e29990283623ae98fc3dfdad

Comment: I have an answer. According to one of the autors, (https://twitter.com/kzu/status/717543814731317248), Xamarin is not a supported platform for this package yet. So it means that you'll have to either wait for an update or find anothet package.

Comment: It says Xamarin is the author, I guess I assumed if Xamarin created it, they would have created it to work with Xamarin built apps.  I'll see if I can find another package though all the ones I tried give me the same error, maybe I'll have to switch to another protocol.  Thanks!

Comment: Wait, so this question was answered as the solution, yet you say maybe you have to switch to other protocols. Did Luis's answer work for you?